# why innerHTML is not able to set the value of id = 'result' field to show the interest ..?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, web-developer-toolbar

[i am not able to get the desired output of getting the simple interest....here innerhtml is not responding to set the value of id = 'result' field......here i have posted my code part..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun1()
    {
      var a = document.getElementById('p').value ;
      var b = document.getElementById('n').value ;
      var c = document.getElementById('r').value ;
      var result = document.getElementById('result');

      result.innerHTML = "The interest is" + (p*n*r/100) ;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1">
    <label> Enter Principal amount :
        <input type="text" id="p"><br>
    </label>

    <label> Enter no. of years :
        <input type="text" id="n"><br>
    </label>

    <label> Enter rate  :
        <input type="text" id="r"><br>
    </label>
   
    <button type="submit" onclick="fun1()"> calculate </button>

    <p id="result">
   </p>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

][[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn2t8.png)1]

Comment: i have set the input type to number .....

Comment: submit buttons submit forms. You need to cancel the submit or it is going to post your form to the server. Use your browser console to see errors.

Comment: Your variables are named different from your calculation. abc, pnr. It's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are a,b,c, not p,n,r. So use a,b,c to calculate result. And use preventDefault() when the form is submitted so that the page does not refresh.

```js
    function fun1(event)
    {
    event.preventDefault()
      var a = document.getElementById('p').value ;
      var b = document.getElementById('n').value ;
      var c = document.getElementById('r').value ;
      var result = document.getElementById('result');

      result.innerHTML = "The interest is" + (a*b*c/100) ;
    }
```

```html
<form name="form1" onSubmit = "fun1(event)">
    <label> Enter Principal amount :
        <input type="text" id="p"><br>
    </label>

    <label> Enter no. of years :
        <input type="text" id="n"><br>
    </label>

    <label> Enter rate  :
        <input type="text" id="r"><br>
    </label>
   
    <button> calculate </button>

    <p id="result">
   </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Add some text on what you did

Comment: @epascarello what i did is explained in the first reply

Comment: I see no explanation anywhere. No comments, not text in your answer.

Comment: @epascarello I added

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your formula is a * b * c, small typo.

You have a button of type submit inside a form. To fix this, pass the event object to the function and disable the default behaviour.

```
<button onclick="fun1(event)">

fun1(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  ...
}
```